# The definition of $X_T$ for a martingale and stopping

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

After learning martingale theory for some time, I am confused with martingale with stopping time. 
Assume $T$ is a stopping time of the filtration space $\left(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\left\{ \mathscr{F}_{n}\right\} _{n\in \mathbb{N}},P\right)$ and $\left\{ X_{n}\right\} _{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a (sub-, super-,)martingale, then we define $X_{T}\left(\omega\right)=X_{T\left(\omega\right)}\left(\omega\right)$.

My question is that since $T\in\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{ \infty\right\}$, if $P\left(T=\infty\right)>0$, what is $X_{T}$ if $T=\infty$ ? If $X_{n}$ converges to $X_{\infty}$ a.e., it is trivial. What if $X_{n}$ doesn't converge? I have searched many textbooks, but none of them explains it clearly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$X_T$ is defined only when one of the following two conditions holds:

1) $T$ is a finite stopping time

2) The martingale converges to a random variable $X_{\infty}$ in some sense ( a.s., in mean etc).

In cae 2) is is understood that we are using $X_{\infty}$ to define $X_T$.

You cannot define $X_T$ without either of these assumptions.

Comment: However, in many optional sampling theorems, we do not need the finiteness of stopping time. So when they mention $X_T$, does it imply that $X_n$ converges?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying. If $T$ is not finite you have to assume that the martingale converges.

Comment: I feel it is a little bit odd since we need to prove the convergence first rather than using "$X_T$" directly.

Comment: In some contexts (non-negative supermartingale, for example) you sometimes see $X_\infty$ being set to $0$ in default of a better choice.  But if nothing is said about $X_T$ on $\{T=\infty\}$, the author may have overlooked something. Where did you encounter this problem, if one may ask?